# Phenomenon of waves transforming at focus

Tags: optics, waves, geometric-optics, lenses, photonics

In the following image, we have a plane wave that travels through a lens, such that it comes to a focus:

[image]

As we can see, the lens transforms the plane wave into a convex wave. But once the convex wave comes to a focus, it transforms into a concave wave. What is this phenomenon that occurs at the focus, where the convex wave transforms into a concave wave, and how/why does it occur?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focus just the location wh re the optical wave lengths of all paths are same. Nothings "happens" there. Remember, a sphere is convex on the outside but concave on the inside.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So are you saying that those waves are actually spherical wavefronts, with the focus being the centre of the sphere?

Comment: Yes, that is a good way of looking at it. Note that the same is true on the object side. In your example all rays emerge from a single point and converge to a single focus point.

Comment: If you want to have a look at what this looks like in Gaussian beam optics, it's worth checking out the Gouy phase (e.g. here: https://www.rp-photonics.com/gouy_phase_shift.html), and you'll see that there is a phase shift of $\pi$ as the beam goes through a focus.

Comment: @Holzner  This should be just a sign change in sign or convention.